# How to fix trailing data error on model update

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

I have been fighting with this issue for weeks and am at wits end. On the surface it seems like a very straightforward fix, however nothing I have tried has worked. I have exhausted many links on Google to this same issue. The error occurs on all models, not just the one in my screenshots, it is across the board.

**Here are the specs:**

- Laravel 5.7
- Ubuntu 16.04
- SQL Server 2016
- ODBC Driver 17
- PHP 7.2.15

**Here is the issue:**

When updating a model using mass assignment, I receive the following error:
`InvalidArgumentException with message 'Trailing data'`

**Here is what I have tried: (in many combinations)**

- Add $dateFormat to my model (tried both 'Y-m-d H:i:s' and 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u')
- Added attribute mutators to the timestamps columns (created_at, updated_at, deleted_at) for both GET and SET
- Adding the timestamp columns into $dates and also $casts

It seems the issue is with the trailing data of ".000" but shouldn't my mutators fix that? Also, I tried updating the date format to Y-m-d H:i:s.u with ".u" at the end, however that produces the following error:
`SQLSTATE[22007]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. (SQL: update [programs] set [title] = New title, [updated_at] = 2019-02-12 15:27:40.000000 where [id] = 1)`

Here is my model:

```
namespace App\Classes\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Program extends Model
{
    protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u';

    protected $fillable = [
    'program_id',
    'user_id',
    'title',
    'westco_service_id',
    'allow_changes',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'deleted_at',
    ];

    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', strtotime($value));
    }

    public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', strtotime($value));
    }

    public function getDeletedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        return date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', strtotime($value));
    }

    public function setCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s.i', strtotime($value));
    }

    public function setUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['updated_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', strtotime($value));
    }

    public function setDeletedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['deleted_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s.u', strtotime($value));
    }

    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

Here is my tinker session:
`
Psy Shell v0.9.9 (PHP 7.2.15-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman

> > > $pr = \App\Classes\Models\Program::findOrFail(1)
> > >       => App\Classes\Models\Program {#3325
> > >            id: "1",
> > >            author_id: "6",
> > >            title: "Behavioral Health: PTP",
> > >            created_at: "2018-08-23 16:47:18.000",
> > >            updated_at: "2018-08-23 16:47:18.000",
> > >            deleted_at: null,
> > >            westco_service_id: null,
> > >            allow_changes: null,
> > >          }
> > >       $pr->update(['title' => 'New title']);
> > >       InvalidArgumentException with message 'Data missing'
> > >       `

Screenshot of my tinker session:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qla3.jpg

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: If you do `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("2018-08-23 16:47:18.000"))` in tinker, what output do you get?

Comment: Don't post images of code... Code is `text`; post it as such. Thank you.

Comment: Pasting that into tinker returned the correct timestamp, no error. "2018-08-23 16:47:18"

Comment: Does changing your getCreatedAtAttribute format from `Y-m-d H:i:s.u` to `Y-m-d H:i:s` do anything?

Comment: Travis, when I have the format 'Y-m-d H:i:s' I receive the 'trailing data' error, however when I have the format 'Y-m-d H:i:s.u' i receive the 'data missing' error

Comment: See if [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/carbon-trailing-data-error?page=0) thread helps

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to remove all the $dateFormat attributes from my models. I also had to remove the $dates attribute which doesn't thrill me, however this is something I can work with.